# Cast from instance to interface is banned?

Tags: java, android, interface, casting

Very simple code for test:

```
interface Base {
    void interfaceTest();
    static final String m = "1";
}

interface Child extends Base {
    void interfaceTestChild();
}

class BaseClass implements Base {
    @Override
    public void interfaceTest() {
        System.out.println("BaseClassInterfaceTest");
    }
}

class ChildClass implements Child {

    @Override
    public void interfaceTest() {
        System.out.println("ChildClassInterfaceTest");
    }

    @Override
    public void interfaceTestChild() {
        System.out.println("interfaceTestChild");

    }
}

public class Src {
    public Child testFunc() {
        Base x = new BaseClass();
        return (Child)x;      <==Here got an "ClassCastException"
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Src testSrcInstance = new Src();
        testSrcInstance.testFunc().interfaceTest();
    }
}
```

In the line `return (Child)x;` I got a "ClassCastException" and I feel very confused about it, for `Child` extends `Base`, so `x` should be converted to `Child` successfully. this kind of conversation is imitated by some android codes:

the `getText()` method of `EditText` is:

```
public Editable getText() {
        return (Editable) super.getText();
    }
```

and the super class of `EditText` is `TextView`, of which the `getText()` method is:

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

mText is a `CharSequence`, and note that Editable extends CharSequence, so you can see, these android codes cast `CharSequence` to `Editable`, just as me, cast `Base` to `Child`, any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in the line return (Child)x; i got a "ClassCastException", i feel very confused about it, for Child extends Base, so x should be converted to Child successfully.

No, it will only work if `x` *actually refers to an instance of some type which implements `Child`. In this case, it doesn't - it only refers to an instance of `BaseClass`. That doesn't specify any behaviour for `interfaceTestChild()`, so what would expect to happen if you'd been able to call it?

```
Base x = new BaseClass();
// Imagine this had worked...
Child child = (Child)x;
// What would this do? There's no implementation!
child.interfaceTestChild();
```

Java only lets you cast to a type which the value actually supports - i.e. some type in the inheritance hierarchy of the object that the value refers to.